# ValueError: Number of labels=1993 does not match number of samples=1994

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, decision-tree, valueerror

Hi I am new to Machine Learning and working on a fun project based on Crime Prediction. I ran into an error before which is now fixed but unfortunately, the following code block is returning a new error. I am using the datasets provided on the [UCI ML Repo](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml//datasets/Communities+and+Crime). I have checked similar posts but haven't found any relevant solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

df_d=pd.read_csv('communities-crime-full.csv')
df
df['highCrime'] = np.where(df['ViolentCrimesPerPop']>0.1, 1, 0)
Y = df['highCrime']

# print('total len is ',len(Y))
initial=pd.read_csv('communities-crime-full.csv')
initial = initial.drop('communityname', 1)
initial = initial.drop('ViolentCrimesPerPop', 1)
initial = initial.drop('fold', 1)
initial = initial.drop('state', 1)
initial = initial.drop('community', 1)
initial = initial.drop('county', 1)
skipinitialspace = True

feature_name=list(initial)
#initial=initial.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
initial = initial.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
New_data=initial.fillna(initial.mean())
# print('before...')
# print(initial)
# print('after...')
# print(New_data)  
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3)
# clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(New_data, Y)
clf
fold=df['fold']
scores = cross_val_score(clf, New_data, Y,fold,'accuracy',10)
print('cross_val_accuracy is ',scores) 
print('cross_val_accuracy_avg is ',np.array(scores).mean()) 
scores = cross_val_score(clf, New_data, Y,fold,'precision',10)
print('cross_val_precision is ',scores) 
print('cross_val_precision_avg is ',np.array(scores).mean()) 
scores = cross_val_score(clf, New_data, Y,fold,'recall',10)
print('cross_val_recall is ',scores) 
print('cross_val_recall_avg is ',np.array(scores).mean())
```

The error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-444381be2864> in <module>()
     25 clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3)
     26 # clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
---> 27 clf = clf.fit(New_data, Y)
     28 clf
     29 fold=df['fold']

/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    281         if len(y) != n_samples:
    282             raise ValueError("Number of labels=%d does not match "
--> 283                              "number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples))
    284         if not 0 <= self.min_weight_fraction_leaf <= 0.5:
    285             raise ValueError("min_weight_fraction_leaf must in [0, 0.5]")

ValueError: Number of labels=1993 does not match number of samples=1994
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you have one more "label" than "samples".
This means that there is one more input that you have outputs for.

However, I think that is not actually your problem. It seems you were accidentally using data you previously loaded into ram, which had a problem with its dimensions.

in your code there is:

```
df_d=pd.read_csv('communities-crime-full.csv')
```

that should probably be:

```
df=pd.read_csv('communities-crime-full.csv')
```

the resulting code will be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

df=pd.read_csv('communities-crime-full.csv')
df['highCrime'] = np.where(df['ViolentCrimesPerPop']>0.1, 1, 0)
Y = df['highCrime']

# print('total len is ',len(Y))
initial=pd.read_csv('communities-crime-full.csv')
initial = initial.drop('communityname', 1)
initial = initial.drop('ViolentCrimesPerPop', 1)
initial = initial.drop('fold', 1)
initial = initial.drop('state', 1)
initial = initial.drop('community', 1)
initial = initial.drop('county', 1)
skipinitialspace = True

feature_name=list(initial)
#initial=initial.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
initial = initial.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
New_data=initial.fillna(initial.mean())
# print('before...')
# print(initial)
# print('after...')
# print(New_data)  
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3)
# clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(New_data, Y)
clf
fold=df['fold']
scores = cross_val_score(clf, New_data, Y,fold,'accuracy',10)
print('cross_val_accuracy is ',scores) 
print('cross_val_accuracy_avg is ',np.array(scores).mean()) 
scores = cross_val_score(clf, New_data, Y,fold,'precision',10)
print('cross_val_precision is ',scores) 
print('cross_val_precision_avg is ',np.array(scores).mean()) 
scores = cross_val_score(clf, New_data, Y,fold,'recall',10)
print('cross_val_recall is ',scores) 
print('cross_val_recall_avg is ',np.array(scores).mean())
```

This results in:

```
cross_val_accuracy is  [0.81       0.825      0.805      0.8        0.82914573 0.77386935
 0.85427136 0.83417085 0.80904523 0.8040201 ]
cross_val_accuracy_avg is  0.8144522613065327
cross_val_precision is  [0.90740741 0.86290323 0.84677419 0.84       0.85826772 0.85714286
 0.92105263 0.92592593 0.85950413 0.90566038]
cross_val_precision_avg is  0.8784638467535306
cross_val_recall is  [0.77777778 0.856      0.84       0.84       0.872      0.768
 0.84       0.8        0.832      0.768     ]
cross_val_recall_avg is  0.8193777777777778
```

looks like some learning is indeed happening!